# Is there a way to conditionally copy claims in custom policies?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, identity-experience-framework

We want to return the user email as one of the claims after signin. However, the email is in different claims depending on how the user signed in or even after they just signed up. Is there a way to merge them all into a single `email` claim?

Our current workaround is to merge them in the very last step by just specifying the claim multiple times. However, when creating a SAML policy, this will create multiple claims and cause errors. We want to merge at an earlier stage.

```xml
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="trustFrameworkPolicy" Required="true" DefaultValue="{policy}" />

        <!-- If the user used social sign in -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <!-- Required when the user just signed up and still has the "sign up session" -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <!-- Get email from local account - must not set default value -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="email" />

        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

What I tried so far:

```xml
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopySignInNameToEmail" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim"/>
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim"/>
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

However, this will fail if the input claim is empty or not yet present.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can try using the ‘FormatStringMultipleClaims’ type of claim transformation method as below by giving input claims as multiple attributes and then merging the output claims as desired in a single string as below: -

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateEmailIDFromFirstNameDisplayNameLastName" 
 TransformationMethod="FormatStringMultipleClaims">
 <InputClaims>
 <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" 
  TransformationClaimType="inputClaim1" />
 <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" 
   TransformationClaimType="inputClaim2" />
 </InputClaims>
 <InputParameters>
 <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0} {1}" />
 </InputParameters>
 <OutputClaims>
 <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" 
   />
 </OutputClaims>
 </ClaimsTransformation>
```

•   The above transformation uses C# String.Format method in which the input claims act as string format {0} and {1} parameter which supports string claims transformation expressions.

•   Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimstransformations

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this. It would be better to have a real conditional logic, but I will try this anyways.